# Sending an UIImage to a web service that only accepts JSON (via RestKit)

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, uiimage, restkit

I'm having trouble sending an UIImage object to my REST web service 
that only accepts JSON as input. 
I have my object mappings all set and it works to generate the JSON 
just fine until it gets to any UIImages.

I read this page about loading the image in separately: 
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Attach-a-File-to-an-RKObjectLoader 
but this always changes the content-type from application/json to 
application/xxx-form-url-encoded (or whatever it is).

So what is the best way to accomplish this without using RKParams?

I found another link here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/restkit/QcTPucXXn4o/41IcKDCeoGAJ that talked about an earlier version of 
RestKit where you could use **propertiesForSerialization** from the 
**RKObjectMappable** protocol but that protocol and method no longer seem 
to be available in 0.10.0.

Is there some way in the new version that will allow you to replace 
the contents of the UIImage with base64 encoded data (therefore JSON 
safe) before trying to serialize it?

Or are there any other solutions? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this with RestKit by saving to an "imageData" property and encoding the image in base64.

This isn't great for CoreData, though, so instead I wrote it so that when getting images from the server (encoded in base64), it saves the image to disk and then stores the path in Core Data instead. Then when pushing the image to the server, it finds the file on the disk, encodes to base64, and then includes that in the JSON.

It's not a perfect method, but if you're not sending images back and forth a lot it works pretty well.

Comment: Nice great idea. So how do you find the file on disk and encode to base64? Is that all just done before you call "postObject" and postObject just knows to use the imageData field?

Comment: I added the `willSave` method to the managedObject. Basically I have an `imagePath` property on my object. RestKit maps the encoded image data to imagePath, but then in `willSave`, I intercept the data, save it to disk, and then store the path to the image instead of the image data itself in `imagePath`. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using RKParams and just changing your serializationMIMEType?

```
    RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];;
    objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

Comment: Yes. The RKParams seem to override any object manager settings with the multipart/form encoding. it's quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out one way to do it.

I ended up creating an extra NSString property for each UIImage and that is what I use to map with instead of the actual UIImage. Then before I postObject, I generate the base64 code for each image and populate the NSString properties accordingly.

Not the greatest way and still curious to see what others come up with.